# MediaWiki Namespace Protection (Read Access)

Tags: security, wiki, mediawiki

I have a question about my MediaWiki installation.

First of all, I know about the security issues that's been stated in the main MediaWiki documentation.

We want to have a corporate wiki. While it is generally considered as a worst practice, I am planning to use seperate namespaces for projects so we can have a page titled "Project scope" in every project without a collision.

Another reason for this choice was the namespace protection feature of the MediaWiki. But when I wanted to configure it, I realized that it can only restrict editing in a namespace. Is there any way to restrict reading in a namespace?

I tried some other wikis too yet MediaWiki is the most familiar and simple one for us to use, so it is probably the final solution.

**I don't want to use an extension unless there is absolutely no other way to do this.**

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Restricting reading is tricky if you don't want to make the whole wiki private or if you need granular permissions. The only maintained extension to do this is Lockdown. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lockdown
It may have less features than other extensions to do the same, but should be rather reliable; please report bugs/experience with it.